# Find $x+y$ for the given conditions

Tags: systems-of-equations, absolute-value

Here's a question that was asked in the [International Kangaroo Math Contest 2017](http://ikmc.kangaroo.org.pk/). Since I get a little confused when I solve equations having the absolute function, so I couldn't get the required answer.

**The Question:**

> What is the value of $x+y$ if $\vert x\vert+x+y=5$
>    and $x+\vert y\vert-y=10?$

**The Answer:** The answer given in the key is $x+y=1$.

**What I Tried:**

I first added both the equations to get
$$\vert x\vert+\vert y\vert+ 2x=15$$
So I got nothing. Then I subtracted the second equation from the first to get
$$\vert x\vert -\vert y\vert+2y=-5$$
And still I got nothing. I can't figure out any other operation that I can perform on these equations. So please help me with this.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Check four cases: $x>0$ or $x<0$; $y>0$ or $y<0$. When you know the sign of $x$ and $y$, you can remove the absolute values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need only check the two cases

- $y \geq 0 \Rightarrow x+|y|-y =x = 10 \stackrel{1st\:eqn.}{\Rightarrow}y < 0 \mbox{ Contradiction!}$
- $x \leq 0 \Rightarrow  |x|+x+y = y =5 \stackrel{2nd\:eqn.}{\Rightarrow}x=10 \mbox{ Contradiction!}$

So, if there is any solution, then $x>0$ and $y < 0$. Now you need only solve
\begin{eqnarray*}
2x + y& = & 5\\
x - 2y & = & 10
\end{eqnarray*}
$\Rightarrow x= 4$ and $y =-3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! ;)